# What's best practice when handling "less than" and "greater than" symbols when importing otherwise numeric values?

Tags: r, dplyr, readr

This is a general question about best practice.

I'm using tidyverse packages to import, read, and then manipulate clinical lab data from a CSV. With clinical data, it's typical to report values outside the limits of quantification with "less than" or "greater than" symbols, eg <250 mg/dL or >2500 mg/dL. So you'll often have a column with mostly numeric values, but a few values that readr will interpret as strings. If I force that column to be numeric, by default the strings are coerced to NAs.

**I'd like to be able to tell readr or dplyr to accept those string values (eg <250, >2500) as numeric values, dropping the characters (eg 250, 2500). Ideally this would be done in a pipeline.**

In general, what's the most flexible and consistent way to handle this situation?

Comment: Read the data normally, then `mydat$myfield <- sub("[<>]", "", mydat$myfield)`, then (assuming no other data massaging is required), `as.numeric` or `as.integer`.

Comment: I don't think any of the `read*` functions (in base, `readr`, `readxl`, `data.table::fread`, `vroom::`, etc) have a method for inferring that `"<250 mg/dL"` should instead be the number `250`. That's on you.

Comment: You could even do `as.numeric(sub("[^-.0-9]", "", mydat$myfield))` to scrub the `mg/dL` as well.

Comment: @r2evans, these comments could/should be an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trusting one of the packages to know what `"<250 mg/dL"` *means* is out of their realm of expertise. For instance, depending on your needs, that value might mean *"effectively 0"* or *"effectively 250"* or something else. Whether this applies to drugs or antibodies or chemicals or whatever, it is absolutely contextual.

Given that, I think the onus is on the programmer/analyst to determine what is appropriate.

Base R method for doing that, assuming that `2:3` reflects the columns you need to fix:

```r
dat <- read.csv(text = csv, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
str(dat)
# 'data.frame': 2 obs. of  3 variables:
#  $ id  : int  1 2
#  $ val1: chr  "<250 mg/dL" ">250 mg/dL"
#  $ val2: chr  ">2500 mg/dL" "<2500 mg/dL"

dat[,2:3] <- lapply(dat[,2:3], function(s) as.numeric(gsub("[^-.0-9]", "", s)))
str(dat)
# 'data.frame': 2 obs. of  3 variables:
#  $ id  : int  1 2
#  $ val1: num  250 250
#  $ val2: num  2500 2500
```

A tidyversion:

```r
library(dplyr)
readr::read_csv(csv) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(val1, val2), ~ as.numeric(stringr::str_replace_all(., "[^-.0-9]", "")))
```

`data.table` is easy, too, adapting the `lapply` above.

---

However, this just assumes that `<250` is the same as `250`, which does not differentiate "real" values from "less than" values. Consider:

```r
csv <-'
id,val1,val2
1,"<250 mg/dL",">2500 mg/dL"
2,">250 mg/dL","<2500 mg/dL"
3,25,2500'
```

How should row 3 be distinguished from the others? For this, I think you'd like need to incorporate more logic, perhaps `ifelse(grepl("<", s), "0", s)`, etc. Again, this is all contextual, so only the analyst knows what rules should go into interpreting those numbers.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Your tidyversion is what I'm looking for, and your logic makes sense. I agree the analyst has to make the call and build out rules for handling "less than" values. 

Mostly, those values will be so low that they'll stand out, so I can just make a note that "any values <250 indicate BLQ." But it's an important distinction to keep in mind nonetheless. Thanks again.

Comment: FYI, if your "rules" for using one or the other get convoluted, you might want to consider `dplyr::case_when` in lieu of numerous nested `if_else`.